# marquee like UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield

How to create marquee like UITextField in Swift. I want to use it in a iOS controller where the user can click on the textfield and select a location, the text is longer enough that I need to implement the marquee Textfield, The text should scroll from right to left.

Comment: There are solutions available for making a marquee `UILabel`. Why don't you look at those and see if you can adapt them to a text field?

Comment: Also, asking like you've done is way too generic, Stack Overflow is better used for very specific problems, like "why does this sort algorithm work backwards?"

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked out

Comment: You'll need to share your code with others to help you make it work.